# Android Studio 4.1 Database Inspector Does Not Detect Application Database

Tags: android-studio, database-inspector

I'm currently trying to use the new Database Inspector that comes with the latest stable release of Android Studio 4.1. The inspector detects the device which is a Pixel 3, API 29 as well as the app process but does not show the app database in the device.

[image]

How do I resolve this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The device reads "Unknown" ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler, I wonder why that is

Comment: Let me try another virtual device to see if that remains the case.

Comment: @MartinZeitler, problem solved! Thank you. The inspector recognizes Nexus 5X API 28 and I can inspect the database now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device reads "Unknown". The reason *might* be,  that the AVD had been created with a previous version of the `avdmanager`. It's not the first time I see errors disappear with a new one AVD, so there seems to be a direct relation (this situation may also cause `emulator` issues). When you'd try a freshly created `Pixel 3 API 29` instead of the `Nexus 5X API 28`, this should also work. It would proof that it's not about the API level used (both are `> 25`), but the version of `avdmanager` used.